# 16.04 64-bit LTS problems with radio buttons, checkboxes and VPN

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, network-manager, gui, vpn

Two weeks ago or so I upgraded my Ubuntu installation from 14.04 to 16.04 and ran into some problems; after a bit of tinkering and asking around the problems were resolved. However, these days I noticed that the rim of the radio boxes, checkboxes are not displayed and the network manager misses the settings for VPN customization.

I have added two screenshots to illustrate the problems. As you can see in the first screenshot the location of the rim of the radio buttons are not displayed, although the dot itself is displayed. In the second one you can see that the option to `Add a VPN connection...` is grayed out and I could not remedy this issue no matter what I did.

[image: VPN problem]

[image: Radio button problem]

Comment: For the VPN issue, check here for which packages you may need to install if they're not already installed: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkManager. For checkboxes, try changing to a different theme and changing back (do they appear correctly when you use a different theme, e.g. Radiance, or reinstall the themes (not sure which packages they are in).

Comment: @JonasCz I double checked if I have all those packages installed and I have them installed. Then I restarted network manager to make sure changes take effect, yet the issue remains.

Answer (score 1):

This may answer your question regarding the invisible edges to radio buttons and checkboxes (but not the VPN question)
There is a similar issue [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2336004).

I'm using xfce4 on 16.04 (after upgrade from 14.04). I think I've had the invisible checkbox issue before on another upgrade. To solve it this time, at first I tried each theme in order but it didn't change things. Then I went to 'Appearance' (on my menus: Settings -> Settings Manager -> Appearance -> Style. )
I then stepped through the various styles until I hit a style where the checkboxes appeared.

Note that I had previously done a re-install of 'ubuntu-artwork' using synaptic (I'm just mentioning this in case it changed things). Synaptic offered other artwork so there might be other styles and themes available that work for you.